# How to horizontally center text inside a span inside table cell, with only access to css of the span?

Tags: css, html-table

I want to align some text horizontally inside one special table cell of the table. The text is located inside a span. The problem is that the HTML code is third-party code. All I can change is the style of the span.

```css
.Change {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Some random text</td>
    <td>Some random text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="Change">Center me</span></td>
    <td>Some random text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A span is naturally an inline-element (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span)). To get the span to take up the width of its parent it needs to become a block-level element which you can achieve by having it as `display: inline-block`. Then the `text-align: center` will know what to do.

```css
.Change {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Some random text</td>
    <td>Some random text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="Change">Center me</span></td>
    <td>Some random text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

<s>`width : 100% ; and margin : 0  auto ;`</s> **did not work** .
i think thats because td has some predefined style like table cell and indent 0

floating to the right and adding width of 100% made it escape soem predefined styles and get the full width which activated the text-align

#### Solution

```css
.Change {
  text-align : center ;
  width : 100%;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>Some random text</td>
<td>Some random text</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span class="Change">Center me</span></td>
<td>Some random text</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

A `<span>` element is inline-block by default. If you can only change the CSS in that element, set the display to block so it will take up the width of the cell:

```css
.Change {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Some random text</td>
    <td>Some random text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="Change">Center me</span></td>
    <td>Some random text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```